# Convert from Price

Tags: c#-4.0

Im attempting to Convert a Price (from an API (code below)).

```
public class Price
{
    public Price();
    public Price(double data);
    public Price(double data, int decimalPadding);
}
```

What I would like to do is compare the price from this API to a Double. Simply trying to convert to Double isnt working as I would have hoped.

```
Double bar = 21.75;
Price price = new Price();

if (Convert.ToDouble(price) >= bar) {
//code
}
```

when I try something like this, I believe it says the value must be lower than infinity.

How can I convert this price so they can be compared?

Comment: Somehow just calling Get on pOrder directly seems more sensible than going through reflection ... if you can't access that because it's private, then you shouldn't be touching it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Convert.ToDouble` cannot magically convert a `Price` object to a double, unless `Price` implements `IConvertible`.

Answer (score 1):

You would need a property in your price object that returns the double and compare that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an **implicit operator** to convert to double. This is as per the [MSDN for "implicit" operator in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx).

E.g.

```
class Price
{
    public static implicit operator double (Price d)
    {
        return d.data;
    }
    public static implicit operator Price (double d)
    {
        return new Price(d);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, for your comparisons, implement `IComparable<double>` and `IEquatable<double>` on your Price class then use the `CompareTo` instead and/or [another operator overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx).